# What is the way to detect token expiry and request user to re-authenticate?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-b2c

We have web app which uses AAD for authentication. We have implemented it using ADAL.NET libraries following this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect

The issue is that if we logon the website and leave it idle for more than an hour, the website does not function correctly after an hour as the token is expired.

Is there a way to identify the token expiry and ask the user to re-authenticate? If possible, grey out the screen for the user and give an option to re-authenticate?

Comment: I don't quite understand you question, because the sample works pretty well. After the token is expired, if you click "Profile" or "To Do List", it will ask you login again automatically. If you check the code in project "TodoListWebApp", in controller "TodoListWebApp.cs" and "UserProfileController.cs", you will see a line `[Authorize]`. That is for telling the web app login again automatically. I am not sure if that's what your want.

Comment: Whenever you get the token note down the time (t1). Before sneding any request to API  check whether whether (current time - t1)< 1hr.